# Import libraries/modules in Angular

Tags: angular, node-modules

In Angular

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
```

what exactly does?

To my understanding it should execute file `Observable.ts`, however there is no such file inside "`node_modules/rxjs`". Of course, the same query applies to all import statements. For example where does Angular find `Injectable` and actually what is `Injectable`when

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
```

Comment: `import` doesn't execute the file, it allows you to access it's exported props methods etc.

Comment: Correct, but where are the files?

Comment: there must be a ``index.d.ts`` that exports ``Observable``

Comment: Just looked at one of my project, I see it under `node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import { Observable } from "rxjs"` will go to the definitions file `index.d.ts` in the root of `node_modules/rxjs` which contains all the public exports. Then using [Object desctructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) `{  }` it will take the object  `Observable` & make it available in the your file.